# If we use the python's dictionary data collection and we assign a variable for dictionary's all keys or values why the variable update automatically?

Tags: python, dictionary

for example look at this code it is in python dictionary data collection

```
car = {
"brand": "Ford",
"model": "Mustang",
"year": 1964
}

x = car.keys()

print(x) 

#now I am trying to update the dictionary

car["color"] = "white"

#look I did not reassign the x with car.keys() built in method

print(x)
```

#but this print(x) is giving me updated dictionary's keys why is that?

I expect it should be print the old dictionary keys list not the updating one as long as I don't reassign the variable again with the method

Comment: If you want to capture the dict's keys at some moment in time, use `x = list(car.keys())`.

Comment: I have to admit that the first time I ran into this, I was also rather surprised.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand what you are doing in here. First, you are accessing a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) which is a key-value structure. When you call the dictionary car with a new key (in this case, 'color'), you are updating the original object in memory, which is car.

When you assign the keys of the dictionary object to a variable (in this case x), you are passing by reference, and creating a [view object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects). This means the object x is pointing to the object car directly in memory. So if you change the object car, all the objects that are referencing this object car in memory will be changed.

Check this artible on [pass by reference vs pass by value](https://realpython.com/python-pass-by-reference/)

In general, python uses pass by value on simple objects and pass by reference in complex objects.

Answer (score -1):

Al Baki Akon

x = car.keys()

Here you are storing the reference of list in x.
Note: You are not storing the copy of list.
If you update dictionary, its key will be updated and x also.

Comment: No, they NOT reference list. The dict view objects are not lists